# Append HTML to existing tooltip in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, foreignobject

I am trying to modify the the tooltip in [zalando's tech radar](https://opensource.zalando.com/tech-radar/).

The relevant code is:

```
  function showBubble(d) {
    if (d.active || config.print_layout) {
      var tooltip = d3.select("#bubble text")
        .text(d.label);
      var bbox = tooltip.node().getBBox();
      d3.select("#bubble")
        .attr("transform", translate(d.x - bbox.width / 2, d.y - 16))
        .style("opacity", 0.8);
      d3.select("#bubble rect")
        .attr("x", -5)
        .attr("y", -bbox.height)
        .attr("width", bbox.width + 10)
        .attr("height", bbox.height + 4);
      d3.select("#bubble path")
        .attr("transform", translate(bbox.width / 2 - 5, 3));
    }
  }
```

In order to extend the tooltip I tried doing the following based on the solution [described here](https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/QbqjEw).

My modified code:

```
function showBubble(d) {
    if (d.active || config.print_layout) {
      var tooltip = d3.select("#bubble text");
      tooltip.html("foo"); // this works!
      //tooltip.html(function(d) { d.label}) // d is undefinded here ...
      tooltip.append("div").attr("id", "foo");

      d3.select("#foo").html("This is not shown").attr("style", "block");

      var bbox = tooltip.node().getBBox();

      d3.select("#bubble")
        .attr("transform", translate(d.x - bbox.width / 2, d.y - 16))
        .style("opacity", 0.8);
      d3.select("#bubble rect")
        .attr("x", -5)
        .attr("y", -bbox.height)
        .attr("width", bbox.width + 10)
        .attr("height", bbox.height + 4);
      d3.select("#bubble path")
        .attr("transform", translate(bbox.width / 2 - 5, 3));
    }
  }
```

Can someone give me a hint how to show this extra text?

#### update

the complete code https://github.com/zalando/tech-radar

Comment: you can't just append div to an svg's text element

Comment: you can use function instead of value (`tooltip.html(function(d)`) only if the element has data bound to it (eg using `data` or `datum` methods upon a selection). Not a case here, seeing that it has an id, which is probably "hardcoded" so to say, and not derived from underlying data array element

Comment: I tried this (I think) ... this was not successful. I got and error that d isn't defined.

Comment: I'm just saying *why* d is not defined -- because selection hadn't any data bound to it

Comment: @Oz123 regarding the undefined, the datum you want is already being passed as the first argument of `showBubble`. So, just do `tooltip.html(d.label)`.

Comment: This works, but does not allow me to introduce complex html. d3 will strip all the tags, so `tooltip.html(d.label + "<br>" + "something else")` results in something else not being shown.

Comment: this is probably needs to be done through foreignObject. See here: http://bl.ocks.org/jebeck/10699411

Comment: You are not seeing your html `<br>` tag because the tooltip is SVG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiline text in svg works a little different than HTML. You can't just append `<div>` & `<br>` tags because they don't mean anything in SVG.

So your options are to:

- use a [foreignObject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject) to render HTML within SVG

```js
var tooltip = d3.select("#bubble")
var fo = tooltip.append('foreignObject').attr('width', '100%').attr('height', '100%')
var foDiv = fo.append("xhtml:body").append("xhtml:div").attr('class', 'fe-div').style('background', '#ccc').html("foo <br>2nd line <br>3rd line")
```

```css
html,
body,
svg {
  height: 100%
}

.fe-div {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg viewBox="0 0 240 80" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g id="bubble">
  </g>
</svg>
```

- or use positioned [tspan](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/tspan) elements to break up text like so:

```js
var tooltip = d3.select("#bubble text");
tooltip.html("foo"); // this works!

// Create a tspan for the 2nd line
var tspan1 = tooltip.append("tspan");
tspan1.html("2nd line");
tspan1.attr('x', 0).attr('dy', '1em')

// Create a tspan for the 3rd line
var tspan2 = tooltip.append("tspan");
tspan2.html("3rd line");
tspan2.attr('x', 0).attr('dy', '1em')
```

```css
html,
body,
svg {
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg viewBox="0 0 240 80" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g id="bubble">
    <text y="35"></text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, but it requires me to format SVG instead of using HTML.

Comment: Then you need to append a foreignObject

Comment: I tried that too, but the documentation and the examples I found won't work with v4 of d3.  Tried this example with d3 v4: http://bl.ocks.org/jebeck/10699411 `TypeError: d3.select(...).append(...).attr(...) is null`

Comment: Yes indeed. I missed your first example. Can you give me a hint how to set the div's background?  `var foDiv = fo.append("xhtml:body").append("xhtml:div").html("<div style='backound-color: coral; color:blue'>foo <br>2nd line <br>3rd line</div>");`
    
has no effect

Comment: I've edited the 1st example with 2 options. Either `.style()` the div directly, or give it a class and use regular old css. Remember that this is now html, so use html css properties (`background` instead of `fill`, for example).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194496/discussion-between-ksav-and-oz123).